# How do I add a timer in my game, which directs the game state to "gameover" once it reaches the time limit?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

My game never ends, you can basically click on the button forever. However I tried adding a time limit, but it never changes the game state to "gameover" it only stays in "game". I also want to add a scoreboard which tracks the amount of clicks per instance of game, which saves in the "gameover" state.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import time
import random
import math


def start_game():
    global game_state
    game_state = "game"

    # RESET THE GAME :D
    # Set score to 0 :(
    # start clicking again :p


# Define constants
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

# Game Setup
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
wn.title("COOKIE CLICK GAME THING")
wn.bgcolor("white")

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()

# Keyboard Bindings
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(start_game, "s")

game_state = "splash"

# Main Game Loop
while True:

    # Clear the screen
    pen.clear()

    # Game code here
    if game_state == "splash":
        wn.bgpic("splash.gif")

    elif game_state == "game":
        wn.bgpic("main.gif")

        starting_time = time.time()
        timer = 20

        while (time.time() - starting_time) < timer:
            wn = turtle.Screen()
            wn.title("cookie")
            wn.bgcolor("white")

            wn.register_shape("cookie.gif")

            cookie = turtle.Turtle()
            cookie.shape("cookie.gif")
            cookie.speed(0)

            clicks = 0

            pen = turtle.Turtle()
            pen.hideturtle()
            pen.color("black")
            pen.penup()
            pen.goto(0, 240)
            pen.write(f"Clicks: {clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))


            def clicked(x, y):
                global clicks
                clicks += 1
                pen.clear()
                pen.write(f"Clicks: {clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))


            cookie.onclick(clicked)

            wn.mainloop()

        # Game logic here

    elif game_state == "gameover":
        wn.bgpic("game_over.gif")






    # Update the screen
    wn.update()
```

Comment: In your loop you never change the game state, without the definitive altering of state based on some action you will never leave the current state you are in...try something like `game_state = input('which game state?')` then the next time the loop iterates your state will be different. This should get you to the spot you need to figure out this on your own

Answer (score 0):

Your program depends on states changing in response to events but your `while True:` design potentially blocks some or all of those events.  Using *timer events*, I've reworked your program into design that you should be able to build upon to complete your game:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FONT = ('Courier New', 32, 'normal')

clicks = 0

def clicked(x, y):
    global clicks

    clicks += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(f"Clicks: {clicks}", align='center', font=FONT)

def start_game():
    screen.bgpic("main.gif")
    screen.title('cookie')

    cookie.onclick(clicked)
    cookie.showturtle()

    pen.write(f"Clicks: {clicks}", align='center', font=FONT)

    screen.ontimer(end_game, 20_000)  # in milliseconds

def end_game():
    cookie.onclick(None)
    screen.bgpic("game_over.gif")
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(f"Final: {clicks}", align='center', font=FONT)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
screen.title("COOKIE CLICK GAME THING")
screen.register_shape("cookie.gif")
screen.bgpic("splash.gif")

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.penup()
pen.sety(240)

cookie = Turtle()
cookie.hideturtle()
cookie.shape("cookie.gif")

screen.onkeypress(start_game, 's')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```